# How to load a window 2 times after each other?

Tags: c#, wpf

Have ben looking for a solution to this prob for some time now but i cant seem to find an answer.

I have a MainWindow from where i want to load a "gameWindow" 2 times from a button. i want the second window to load after the first close.

If you can imagine this idea:

```
private void Action_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (blueTeamMap != null && redTeamMap != null)
    {
        GameWindow matchBlueTeam = new GameWindow(playersBlueTeam, playersRedTeam, blueTeamMap);
        matchBlueTeam.Show();
        while (matchBlueTeam != null)
        {
            // wait for window to resign
        }

        GameWindow matchRedTeam = new GameWindow(playersBlueTeam, playersRedTeam, redTeamMap);
        matchRedTeam.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: use event: e.g. first window's `Closed` event handler to open the second window.

Comment: But wont it just countinue to open the 3rd window then? Or am i missing something?

Comment: no, only if you are asking the second window to open the third one in its `Closed` event..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this: edit your code to be like this

```
//your code here.

//add event here
matchBlueTeam.FormClosed += FormName_FormClosed;
matchBlueTeam.Show();
```

Add the event handler:

```
private void FormName_FormClosed(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   //unregister first window from event
   ((GameWindow)sender).FormClosed -= FormName_FormClosed;

   if (blueTeamMap != null && redTeamMap != null)
   {
      //pop second window
      GameWindow matchRedTeam = new GameWindow(playersBlueTeam, playersRedTeam,     redTeamMap);
      matchRedTeam.Show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Unless you are going to use matchBlueTeam again (and don't want to repeat behaviour, which is unlikely), there's no need to unregister the event.

Comment: @Jcl: Yes sure, you're right as there is no need to unregister the event. I just consider a best practice to always unregister from events when no longer needed to avoid memory leaks, but in this case is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `matchBlueTeam` window closes, and `GameWindow` has a `Closed` event, something like:

```
private void Action_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (blueTeamMap != null && redTeamMap != null)
    {
        GameWindow matchBlueTeam = new GameWindow(playersBlueTeam, playersRedTeam, blueTeamMap);
        matchBlueTeam.Closed += (s,e) => { 
            GameWindow matchRedTeam = new GameWindow(playersBlueTeam, playersRedTeam, redTeamMap);
            matchRedTeam.Show();
        };
        matchBlueTeam.Show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure i understand the: "matchBlueTeam.Closed += (s,e) => {}" syntax. but i get the idea.

How do i make it compile?

Comment: That's a lambda expression that creates an anonymous method. Should compile on c# 3.5 (or 4.0, not sure). You can learn more about lambda expressions [on this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) for anonymous methods.

Comment: I'd bind the event handler first, then call Show (to be 100% sure nothing gets in the way of the handler binding)

Comment: @Alex , that's right. I'll edit accordingly. Put it like that for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ask for the ShowDialog() on the window method. it than waits for the window to close.

```
Window1 w1 = new Window1();
w1.ShowDialog();
Window2 w2 = new Window2();
w2.ShowDialog();
```

Or with events:

```
        //////Code    
        Window1 w1 = new Window1();
        w1.Closed += v_Closed;
        w1.Show();
    }


    void v_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 w1 = (Window1)sender;
        w1.Closed -= v_Closed;
        Window2 w2 = new Window2();
        w2.Show();
    }
```

Comment: That would prevent the rest of the program to respond to other events. You are assuming those are the only two windows and there's nothing else going on. I personally don't like that behaviour.

Comment: He didn't say what has to happen in the windows so this is the easiest way.

Comment: Yep, that's why I didn't downvote the answer (since it's correct). Just saying I personally don't like this behaviour and just prefer keeping the UI thread running on the rest of the app.

Comment: Yes, but if you would like user input than it's the best way.